# an unknown text show in every page header codeigniter

Tags: php, view, header

An unknown text ed shown in every pages of codeigniter website.I try a lot to find the mistake but unable to fix the issue,Kindly tell me the issue,I also search the text in models and views files

Screenshot Image below ..

[image]

Comment: check in your controller function  or if you call model function , any  value you echo

Comment: You're echoing something somewhere, somehow. We can't help you finding out where, you need to check all files that's invoked. Router, config, controllers, models etc that's loaded/used in those calls where it shows up.

Comment: but,why the text shows in all pages

Comment: Because _"You're echoing something somewhere, somehow"_. It can be in your views as well. Make sure that you haven't accidentally written `ed` somewhere in a header or something. We can't debug this for you.

Comment: Check controller class,function,models .... any echo,var_dump,print etc.

Comment: The Problem got fixed.I accidentally write ed in a Model File.

Comment: Check controller class,function,models .... any echo,var_dump,print etc.Also    check your all view,template... you include for any  echo,var_dump,print etc .If still it showing text and using multiple view then inspect mode and try to understand its location(may be in header.php,menu.php ....).Search that string in your all code using  IDE (may it mistakenly typed )